# How to stop the data doubling in jTable after clicking on button?

Tags: java, loops, swing, jtable

i'm having this problem where my data shows onclick, but then when i click again it just doubles. Even after i add new data to the table.

```
    private void ShowBtnActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
        
        BufferedReader br = null;
        try {
            String filePath = "BookstoreManagement/BookStore.txt";
            File file = new File(filePath);
            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
            String firstLine = br.readLine().trim();
            String[] columnsName = firstLine.split(",");           
           
            DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel)table.getModel();
            Object[] tableLines = br.lines().toArray();
            
            for (Object tableLine : tableLines) {
                String line = tableLine.toString().trim();
                String[] dataRow = line.split(",");
                model.addRow(dataRow);
                //System.out.print(Arrays.toString(dataRow));
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(BookRegistration.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } 
    }
```

this is the code

Comment: [`DefaultTableModel#setRowCount `](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableModel.html#setRowCount(int)) - use it before you load the new rows and set the row count to `0`.  Alternatively (and probably more safely), create a new instance of `DefaultTableModel` and fill it, once completed, set the model to the table

Comment: Thank you very much. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

## You could...

Reset the `TableModel`'s content.  When using `DefaultTableModel`, you can simply set the row count to `0`

```
DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel)table.getModel();
model.setRowCount(0);
```

## You could...

Build a new `TableModel` from scratch.  This is probably a safer option, as it doesn't rely on you known what type of `TableModel` the `JTable` is currently using.

```
 DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel();
Object[] tableLines = br.lines().toArray();

for (Object tableLine : tableLines) {
    String line = tableLine.toString().trim();
    String[] dataRow = line.split(",");
    model.addRow(dataRow);
    //System.out.print(Arrays.toString(dataRow));
}
table.setModel(model);
```

It will probably also be faster as the model isn't causing the table to trigger new updates each time you add a new row

Comment: Thank you very much, you have been very helpful.